# Django create date list from existing objects

Tags: django, datetime, django-views

i come with this doubt abobt how to make a linked dates list based on existing objects, first of all i have a model with a DateTimeField which stores the date and hour that the object was added.

I have something like:

|pk|name|date
|1|name 1|2016-08-02 16:14:30.405305
|2|name 2|2016-08-02 16:15:30.405305
|3|name 3|2016-08-03 16:46:29.532976
|4|name 4|2016-08-04 16:46:29.532976

And i have some records with the same day but different hour, what i want is to make a list displaying only the unique days:

2016-08-02
2016-08-03
2016-08-04

And also because i'm using the CBV DayArchiveView i want to add a link to that elements to list them per day with a url pattern like this:

```
url(r'^archive/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[-\w]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/$', ArticleDayArchiveView.as_view(), name="archive_day"),
```

The truth is that i don't have a clue of how to achieve that, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting unique dates

```
instances = YourModel.objects.all()
unique_dates = list(set(map(lambda x: x.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), instances)))
```

About listing them, your url pattern looks ok. You need to define a view in order to retrieve them and wire up with that url.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to order them, just:

```
sorted_dates = sorted(unique_dates)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked great, also it's possible to order the dates and paginate them? because it displays: the list unordered